# change structure of array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, structure

This is nationality of commune.

i have this array from a multi form post

```
Array
(
    [pid] => Array
        (
        )

    [commune] => Array
        (
            [0] => 64
            [1] => 64
            [2] => 64
            [3] => 64
e.t.c ...
        )

    [nationality] => Array
        (
            [0] => AF
            [1] => AL
            [2] => DE
            [3] => US
e.t.c ...
        )

    [female] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 119
            [3] => 13
e.t.c ...
        )

    [male] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 102
            [3] => 16
e.t.c ...
        )

    [send] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

and i need to change like this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => AF
            [female] => 4
            [male] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => AL
            [female] => 0
            [male] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => DE
            [female] => 119
            [male] => 102
        )

    [3] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => US
            [female] => 13
            [male] => 16
        )
)
```

e.t.c ...

if in Array [1] [female] = 0 amd [male] = 0 i need to delete Array [1]


after i need to insert value from [commune], [nationality], [female] and [male] in mysqli

name of columns un table are the same commune,nationality,female,male


Thanks for help

Marc

Comment: Name your form fields like this `data[row-number][commune], data[row-number][nationality]` etc. PHP will handle the rest for you.

Comment: This is definitely one of those do the job for me questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$ar_val = array('pid' => array(), 'commune' => array(64,64,64,64),'nationality' => array('AF','AL','DE','US'),'female' => array(4,0,119,13),'male' => array(2,0,102,16), 'send' => array());

foreach($ar_val as $ar_key=>$ar_val){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($ar_val as $arry_val){
        $output[$i][$ar_key] = $arry_val;       
        $i++;
    }   
}
print_r($output);
```

**`$ar_val`** is the main array in which you are having your form values.

You can try to test this code as well. Its working for me.

**Above code will change below array output:**

```
Array
(
    [commune] => Array
        (
            [0] => 64
            [1] => 64
            [2] => 64
            [3] => 64
        )

    [nationality] => Array
        (
            [0] => AF
            [1] => AL
            [2] => DE
            [3] => US
        )

    [female] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 119
            [3] => 13
        )

    [male] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 102
            [3] => 16
        )
)
```

**to below array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => AF
            [female] => 4
            [male] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => AL
            [female] => 0
            [male] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => DE
            [female] => 119
            [male] => 102
        )

    [3] => Array
        ( 
            [commune] => 64
            [nationality] => US
            [female] => 13
            [male] => 16
        )
)
```